# JavaFX application doesn't close with swing content

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I try to add `Swing` component to `JavaFX` application. I create `SwingNode` object with `JButton` but don't add this element to main `Scene`. After closing main stage, application stay running. What I need to do to fix this?

Example here:

```
public class SwingFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);

        AnchorPane pane1 = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane pane2 = new AnchorPane();
        pane1.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane2, 100, 50));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!"));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add `SwingNode` to the scene ?

Comment: Because when initialization occurs, I don't want this element to be in the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happens, but I can give you some dirty solution to fix it. Application stay running after closing if you create `SwingNode` and don't add it to `Scene`. So you need to add `SwingNode` to `Scene`, but with zero size. This must fix your problem.

Example:

```
public class SwingFx extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create pane with SwingNode
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode);
        StackPane paneWithSwing = new StackPane(swingNode);

        // create invisible pane to initialize SwingPane in Scene
        Pane invisiblePane = new Pane(paneWithSwing);
        invisiblePane.setPrefWidth(0);
        invisiblePane.setPrefHeight(0);
        invisiblePane.setOpacity(0);

        // create Scene without visible SwingPane
        Button button = new Button("Set SwingNode");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            invisiblePane.getChildren().clear();
            stage.getScene().setRoot(paneWithSwing);
        });
        StackPane originalPane = new StackPane(invisiblePane, button);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(originalPane, 320, 180));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> swingNode.setContent(new JButton("Click me!")));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to see a solution without a zero size pane